# Android App crashed without any reason

Tags: java, android

I'm really new to Android so it's possible that my fault is very stupid..But my application crashed without any for me viewable reason.

My LogCat output:

```
05-25 19:15:25.656: D/dalvikvm(25858): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
05-25 19:15:30.171: D/AndroidRuntime(25858): Shutting down VM
05-25 19:15:30.171: W/dalvikvm(25858): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e1aa08)
05-25 19:15:30.251: E/AndroidRuntime(25858): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 19:15:30.251: E/AndroidRuntime(25858): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{de.mo.securegate/de.mo.securegate.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-25 19:15:30.251: E/AndroidRuntime(25858):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2228)
05-25 19:15:30.251: E/AndroidRuntime(25858):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
05-25 19:15:30.251: E/AndroidRuntime(25858):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
05-25 19:15:30.251: E/AndroidRuntime(25858):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1250)
05-25 19:15:30.251: E/AndroidRuntime(25858):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-25 19:15:30.251: E/AndroidRuntime(25858):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-25 19:15:30.251: E/AndroidRuntime(25858):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5229)
05-25 19:15:30.251: E/AndroidRuntime(25858):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-25 19:15:30.251: E/AndroidRuntime(25858):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-25 19:15:30.251: E/AndroidRuntime(25858):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:799)
05-25 19:15:30.251: E/AndroidRuntime(25858):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
05-25 19:15:30.251: E/AndroidRuntime(25858):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-25 19:15:30.251: E/AndroidRuntime(25858): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-25 19:15:30.251: E/AndroidRuntime(25858):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:161)
05-25 19:15:30.251: E/AndroidRuntime(25858):    at de.mo.securegate.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:28)
05-25 19:15:30.251: E/AndroidRuntime(25858):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
05-25 19:15:30.251: E/AndroidRuntime(25858):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
05-25 19:15:30.251: E/AndroidRuntime(25858):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
05-25 19:15:30.251: E/AndroidRuntime(25858):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2219)
05-25 19:15:30.251: E/AndroidRuntime(25858):    ... 11 more
```

Any Ideas ?

Comment: What I've learned there is always a reason. Looks like a NullPointerExeption while instantiating an Activity. Have you checked line 161 in ContextWrapper.java?

Comment: line no. 28 in MainActivity causing NPE. show off this line.

Comment: You are probably trying to get the `SharedPreferences` outside of a method. Post that code

Comment: You should post the code around the line where you are calling `getSharedPreferences()`.

Comment: Thanks Guys, this solved it.. I just had to put `getSharedPreferences()` into a method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

line 28 in `MainActivity` throws a `NullPointerException` when try to read some shared preferences. That's what your logcat says:

```
at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:161)
at de.mo.securegate.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:28)
```